# How to authorize a specific route/page to a certain group of people/users after google login with React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm building a react web app, in which I want certain routes to be accessible to certain people, based on their role.
Now, i have been using JWT authentication and authorization, BUT recently I came across auth0/auth2.0 and I realized that in some parts, there's no need to create all the login/sign up functionality with JWT all by myself.

Now, I wanted to ask HOW does one implement authorization to a certain route to a specific user(based on their role) after logging in/sign up with google.?

Because it confuses me that, yes a user doesn't need to create a new account for the web app, BUT how do you then authorize a specific route to them based on their role?
And WHERE do you define this role?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can't achieve this with google oauth alone.
You can use google oauth only for authorization and a database to store user role information, as you do with JWT.

1. Use the token from google auth for authorization.
2. Find the user by email, define the role